# JavaScript: Testing variables for undefined value; testing whether object is array

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-5

1. Is there a difference between `typeof value === "undefined"` and `value === undefined`?
2. Why did JavaScript need `Array.isArray()` in ECMAScript 5? Can't I just call `value instanceof Array` to determine whether an given variable is an array?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
//var value; There is no var declaration. The variable was never declared

// check againts undeclared variables
typeof value === "undefined"; // works

// check againts declared variables with no value
value === undefined; // ReferenceError: value is not defined
```

There are also issues with `undefined = true` being valid. But you don't really care about that. No-one is stupid enough to alter `undefined` globally these days.

I also know of bugs with `instanceof` being broken. I can't give you the exact reason why `Array.isArray` is better though.

You will find criticism on `instanceof` in the [JavaScript Garden](http://bonsaiden.github.com/JavaScript-Garden/#types.instanceof)

If you read [this Article](http://blog.brianhartsock.com/2007/03/08/breaking-instanceof-in-javascript/) It mentions how `instanceof` does not work across seperate frames / windows / iframes.

Because instanceof checks againts `Array` and each window has it's own `window.Array`.

Comment: Thanks! I just tried `var foo; (foo === undefined);` in my FF4 JS console and didn't get a reference error. What gives?

Comment: @FooBarMaximus you get a reference error if you drop `var foo` ;) `typeof` works without the var declaration.