# Check if url param exist using jquery

Tags: jquery

i saw some similar post at Stack, but i want to ask for specific function in jquery that is

`$.urlParam('GETparameter')`

Why simple
`if($.urlParam('GETparameter') === undefined)` 
not working? And why there are complex answers at other questions?

Thank you for answers

Answer (score 12, accepted):

### Update 2021

This is an overdue update, but as  [Frits's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60559314/2026606) notes, using [`URLSearchParams`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URLSearchParams) is now the best approach.

```
const getQueryParameter = (param) => new URLSearchParams(document.location.search.substring(1)).get(param);
```

---

### Answer from 2016

First off, `$.urlParam` is not an inherent jQuery function as far as I can tell, meaning you'll need to define it if you plan on using it.

When looking it up, I found a user-created function of the same name; I am going to assume that this is what you're referring to:

```
$.urlParam = function(name){
    var results = new RegExp('[\?&]' + name + '=([^&#]*)').exec(window.location.href);
    return results[1] || 0;
}
```

It looks like this will return `0` if the parameter is not found, rather than  `undefined`. If this function is in fact the one you're referencing, you'll want to do this instead:

`if($.urlParam('GETparameter') === 0)`

Comment: I also had to check for null before the return. `$.urlParam = function(name){    var results = new RegExp('[\?&]' + name + '=([^&#]*)').exec(window.location.href); if (results === null) {           return 0;  } return results[1]; }`

Comment: Yay for URLSearchParams! :) :) stoked there's finally a better solution available for us to use.

Answer (score 16):

Another solution here is the `URLSearchParams` function.

As an example, if your URL was `https://example.com?foo=bar&baz=qux` you could retrieve all of the parameters and then query the specific one like this:

```
var urlParams = new URLSearchParams(window.location.search); //get all parameters
var foo = urlParams.get('foo'); //extract the foo parameter - this will return NULL if foo isn't a parameter

if(foo) { //check if foo parameter is set to anything
    alert('FOO EXISTS');
}

if(foo == 'bar') { //check if foo parameter is 'bar'
    alert('FOO == BAR');
}
```

Comment: This is clean solution but unfortunately IE doesn't support URLSearchParams.

Comment: @PinakiMukherjee yeah - depending on what you are coding for, most new small websites are ignoring Internet Explorer as a use case. Though it's important to note that IE is still supported by MS until Aug2021, the current usage estimate for IE is between 0.3% and 1.89%, which is an incredibly small percentage of people, who will honestly be dealing with a ton of issues from other websites in any case.

Comment: I agree, IE is like new IE6. Everyone will be happy on her demise :).

Answer (score 1):

If you want to check type of variable, you need to use something like:

```
if (typeof($.urlParam('GETparameter')) === 'undefined') {
  ..
}
```

[typeof documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/pl/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencje/Operatory/Operator_typeof)

Comment: Why is this better than just checking `=== undefined`? See http://www.2ality.com/2013/04/check-undefined.html

Comment: In my opinion it's good practise, because if you don't have defined variable at all, you will get error: "ReferenceError: x is not defined".  Less problems with further debug. See [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6006156/javascript-testing-variables-for-undefined-value-testing-whether-object-is-arr)

Comment: You right, but i always use that syntax to avoid problems and simplify debug process.

Answer (score 0):

You could try this:

```
var url_param       = $(location).attr('href').split("?");
var param           = (url_param[1]);
```

Where `url_param[1]` is your second element in array (in this case your url parameters, if existing).

Then you can check with `if(param!='') { // do something }`